# How can I deal with high disk usage from SQL Server Memory Optimised Tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

We have a SQL Server 2019 database that contains a a large number of memory optimised tables, each set to only persist schema, not data. The tables are used for some calculations, then empties as part of a data warehouse build operation. Currently the tables are empty.

Yesterday the database went into delete only mode because the disks filled completely and unexpectedly. Someone has tried to fix this and the database is back up and running now (but I don't know fully what they did).

However, we are left with the [DBNAME]_MemoryOptimized_FG folder for the database containing almost 2TB of files, meaning very little space is remaining on the disk and it can't currently be expanded.

I've backed up the database and transaction logs (twice), tried to run a checkpoint, tried shrinking files but nothing lowers the disk usage.

Is there anything the community can suggest to assist?

### EDIT

I should have mentioned. We are also using transactional replication on this database (not against memory optimised tables). This is now failing. It seems that somebody performed a very large update on one of the replicated tables and this caused a huge log to build that helped fill the disk. This update is currently failing to replicate. Could this be causing the issue?

Also, I originally wrote 2022 (it's been a long night). I meant 2019. @@VERSION is Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)   Nov  6 2020 16:50:01   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: SQL Server 2022 hasn't been released yet, it's not even in public preview. Anyone using it currently should have folks at Microsoft they're working with (including investigating problems with that pre-release version), and probably under a tight NDA. Are you _sure_ that's what you're running?

Comment: No, it's 2019. No idea why I typed 2022. Must have been thinking Visual Studio :-D

Comment: The MO_FG should compact and remove themselves, if they aren't then that's something to look into. If the log is taking up a ton of space, look at the log reuse description and go from there. We'll need more info like the output of sys.databases or sys.dm_db_xtp_checkpoint_files